# Join Based on the Same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, inner-join

I have two tables such as TableA and TableB.

Schema for TableA:

```
     UoMID
     UoMName
```

Schema for TableB:

```
     ItemID
     ItemName
     UoMID
     D1_UoMID
     D2_UoMID
     D3_UoMID
```

Here I want to Join Both these tables based on UoMID in the TableA and UoMID, D1_UoMID, D2_UoMID and D3_UoMID in the TableB.
I want to retrieve the following columns:

```
     ItemName, UoMName, D1_UoMName, D2_UoMName and D3_UoMName
```

How to retreive the above columns? and How do I identify the UoMName for the Corresponding UoMID, D1_UoMID, D2_UoMID and D3_UoMID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), you can join to the same table multiple times and distinguish the results of the different joins. Try this:

```
SELECT
    ItemName,
    d0.UoMName,
    d1.UoMName as D1_UoMName,
    d2.UoMName as D2_UoMName,
    d3.UoMName as D3_UoMName
from TableB tb
join TableA d0 on d0.UoMID = tb.UoMID
join TableA d1 on d1.UoMID = tb.D1_UoMID
join TableA d2 on d2.UoMID = tb.D2_UoMID
join TableA d3 on d3.UoMID = tb.D3_UoMID;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ta.UoMName, ta1.UoMName, ta2.UoMName ta3.UoMName 
FROM TableA AS ta, TableA AS ta1, TableA AS ta2, TableA AS ta3, TableB AS tb
WHERE ta.UoMID = tb.UoMID
AND ta.UoMID = tb.UoMID
AND ta1.UoMID = tb.D1_UoMID
AND ta2.UoMID = tb.D2_UoMID
AND ta3.UoMID = tb.D3_UoMID
```

You have to give aliases to the tables, if you want to use the same table more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
     b.ItemName,
     (SELECT a1.UoMName FROM TableA a1 WHERE a1.UoMID = b.UoMID) as UoMName,
(SELECT a2.UoMName FROM TableA a2 WHERE a2.UoMID = b.D1_UoMID) as D1_UoMName,
(SELECT a3.UoMName FROM TableA a3 WHERE a3.UoMID = b.D1_UoMID) as D3_UoMName,
(SELECT a4.UoMName FROM TableA a4 WHERE a4.UoMID = b.D1_UoMID) as D3_UoMName,
FROM TableB b
```

Hope this works

Comment: Yuk... that query will perform very poorly indeed. You don't need to make sub-selects!